# How do I get an image to upload to directory in Redactor Editor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, redactor

I am working on making a CMS at the minute. I have got redactor coded so that I can edit text sucessfully with it. However I am now working getting an image upload to work in the text editor and have come across a few problems which I have been stuck on for quite some time.

I have been able to get to the stage where I can choose the image to upload... and then when it uploads, the path of the image goes into the text editor correctly, however the image does not seem to write to the directory.

I am working locally, and have the directory set as /CMS/public/uploads/

Here is my upload function.

```
<?php

// files storage folder
$dir = '/CMS/public/uploads/';

$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
{
    // setting file's mysterious name
    $file = $dir.$_FILES['file']['name'];

    // copying
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $file);

    // displaying file
    $array = array(
        'filelink' => $file
    );

    echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
}

?>
```

This code basically tells the file where to be copied to.

Does anyone have any Idea why this might not be copying the the directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work: change `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['name'], $file);` to `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);`
the `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is the place  where the temporary file is located and from there it is moved to the specified path

***Changed your code a bit: (Hope this works)***

```
<?php
$type = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

$allowed_type = array('image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg');

if(in_array($type, $allowed_type)) {
    // setting file's mysterious name
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $dir = '/CMS/public/uploads/'.$file;

    // copying
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dir);

    // displaying file
    $array = array(
        'filelink' => $file
    );

    echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi there... thanks for your answer... I tried what you said, however the same thing is happening. Its a weird one :/

Comment: Thanks again for the code change... It still doesn't work. The image just isn't writing to the file... do you think its something to do with permissions on localhost?

Comment: It could be something with the configuration of your localhost. I don't know the file size of the file you try to upload but somewhere in the php.ini file there is a limit set to upload size. If your file is bigger than it doesn't work. for me it was called: post_max_size = 10M and upload_max_filesize = 10M but it be something else for you. I tought in most cases this is set to 2M.